# Google People API / Method: contactGroups.list

Tags: php, rest, api, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

This is the sample code that I am using to get my contacts from Google People API. Works fine.

```
$people_service = new Google_Service_PeopleService($client); // TODO: Use service object to request People data

$connections = $people_service->people_connections->listPeopleConnections ('people/me',
    array('personFields' => 'names,emailAddresses,biographies',
    'pageSize' => 25,
    'sortOrder' => 'FIRST_NAME_ASCENDING',
    ));
```

But I couldn't figure out how to list and manage Contact Groups (like friends, family etc.).

This is the code I am trying without success.

```
$groups_list = $people_service->contactGroups->listcontactGroups();
```

Sources I could find:

- https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/people/v1/php/latest/class-Google_Service_PeopleService.html
- https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/list

Comment: I think there is another class with the name of Google_Service_PeopleService_ContactGroup. But still I don't know how to call my groups.

Comment: Please add more detail on what is wrong. Do you get an error? Do you get an empty response?

Comment: Thank you Amos. Mr. Rebot's solution worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you check if you need to call an extra function as indicated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/people/v1/php/latest/class-Google_Service_PeopleService_ListContactGroupsResponse.html)? Follow the [PHP sample](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/php) for printing the names for up to 10 connections.

```
$groups_list = $people_service->contactGroups->listcontactGroups();

$group_list->getContactGroups( );
```

Comment: Interesting part is I tried your suggestion in a moment I saw but didn't work (obviously there was a mistake that I made) . Then I tried many other ways since yesterday. A few minute ago I tried it again and now its working. Thank you Mr. rebot.